# How to add tabs in the cell of tableviewController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

hello I want to know how can I add tabs in the tableviewcontroller like this[image]

I want to add tabs  Contact and About similar to image and also a line between them. These tabs are in the mid of screen not at the bottom.

I have another question is when I press my thumb on this image portion and move my thumb downwards the image size increases. How can I do that. When I do in my controller white background comes up.

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/) for increasing the size of the image portion.

Answer (score 0):

You could put buttons at the bottom of the cell and then have the button handlers reload elements in the cell's view.